# Error when activating a custom plugin on production server

Tags: plugin-development, oop

I'm currently developing a custom plugin. All works well on my local dev environment (Local by Flywheel), but, on production environment, I'm unable to activate the plugin. I get this error message:

`Fatal error: Class 'Activate' not found in /datas/vol3/w4a156338/var/www/my-website/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/ads-toolbox/ads-toolbox.php on line 54`

The 'ads-toolbox.php' file it the plugin main php file and it contains the following:

```
function activate_adstoolbox_plugin() {
    Inc\Base\Activate::activate();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_adstoolbox_plugin' );
```

Line 54 is: `Inc\Base\Activate::activate();`

The class 'Activate' is inside the 'Activate.php' file located in 'inc/Base/' subdirectory and contains:

```
namespace Inc\Base;

class Activate
{
    public static function activate()
    {
        //Some code
    }

}
```

I do not understand why it works locally but not on my hosted site!?

Any idea ?

Comment: Check the difference of your local environment and live...like php version etc

Comment: Can you show where the Activate.php file is being incorporated?

Comment: sounds like a paths issue on your production server.  sometimes you have to tweak where files are being called from.

Comment: What happens when you add `include( __DIR__ . "/inc/Base/activate.php" );` on top of your master file *( ads-toolbox.php)* to be sure that the class file is loaded? As mentioned by @klewis, be sure paths are correct.

Comment: You need the Composer, vendor folder

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @the_hobbes and @Charles, I realized that the file Activate.php was not incorporated. By adding `require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/Base/Activate.php';` to my code as shown below, it works correctly:

```
function activate_adstoolbox_plugin() {
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/Base/Activate.php';
    Inc\Base\Activate::activate();
}
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_adstoolbox_plugin' );
```

Oops! Newbie's error ...